# Herkunft von „Reinfall“

Tags: etymology

Wo kommt das Wort Reinfall her?

Ist es mit [Rheinfall](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GR04963#XGR04963), mit [Reinfal](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GR03777#XGR03777) oder doch mit einem anderem Wort verwandt?

Comment: Wieso willst du einen Zusammenhang zu Rheinfall konstruieren, wenn "Reinfall" doch ganz deutlich und bildlich beschreibt, wie jemand in eine Falle/Fallgrube faellt?  - Davon abgesehen sagt mir "Reinfal" nichts und du hast zwei mal den gleichen Link zu Rheinfall angegeben.

Comment: @DirkLiebhold Ich will gar keinen Zusammenhang *konstruieren*, die Suchmaschine wollte.

Comment: First I've associated as "rainfall", i.e. "regenfall", which is totally bad because it mixes German with English, however the final meaning is not very far from it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Reinfall" (https://www.dwds.de/wb/Reinfall) = (he)rein+Fall

"Rheinfall" = Rhein+Fall

Answer (score 11):

Bei *Reinfal* handelt es sich um eine alte, nicht mehr angebaute Weintraubensorte, die wohl ursprünglich aus dem Friaul stammt und deren ursprünglicher Name Rebulo wohl ins Deutsche verballhornt wurde.

Der *Rheinfall* ist der der größte Wasserfall Europas.

Und ein *Reinfall* ist eine unangenehme Überaschung oder große Enttäuschung

Die drei Begriffe haben nichts miteinander zu tun.